# PHP echos odd characters ("â€œhelloâ€") on OS X installation

Tags: php, macos, echo, mamp, virtualhost

This is my first time with MAC on php, earlier I have been using ubuntu machines for PHP.

I have successfully installed MAMP. and now I have a file(*index.php*) in *htdocs*

```
<?php

   echo “hello”;
```

and its output on *safari* is :

```
â€œhelloâ€
```

I have tried with several different texts, all of them generate absurd output on browser.

Where is the problem in mac, safari or MAMP ?

[image]
**update :**

Without curly quotes the output is `â€˜helloâ€™`

Comment: Did you set the charset to utf-8? `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: curly quotes of doom?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use special quotes like `“` and `”` but use `"` or `'` instead. Be sure to use a simple text editor when you write code and not something like Word, for example, which will replace the simple quote characters to more fancy ones.

PHP doesn't understand the fancy quotes and won't substitute them with `"` or `'`, which have a special meaning in the language.

**So, why didn't it break?** PHP is incredibly forgiving, which has advantages and disadvantages. Consider the following code, which uses a constant:

```
define('HELLO', 'Hello world!');
echo HELLO;
```

This works and will output "Hello world!"

Now, if we pass what looks like a constant to PHP but don't define it, PHP will just output the (inexistent) constant's name instead:

```
echo HELLOWORLD;
```

this will output "HELLOWORLD".

The same happens with the text bit `“hello”` – it tries to look for a constant with that name, doesn't find any, and so just outputs `“hello”`. This only outputs an E_NOTICE error, which may be disabled by default. It is recommended to output *all* errors during development to avoid errors such as this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo “hello”;
```

This will output:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant â€œhelloâ€ - assumed 'â€œhelloâ€'

And indeed, if we tried to add a space between those special quotes, it would fail as constants can't have a space in their name, and so the text can't be interpreted at all:

```
echo “hello world”;
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'worldâ€' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

As to why the special quotes like `“` aren't being displayed properly, this is because of an encoding problem. `“` has an ASCII value above 127 and so can be interpreted in different ways depending on the encoding. Your file is saved in a certain encoding but your server and browser may assume it is in another one, yielding false characters.

Comment: and yes, phpinfo() has whole lot of information. I do have php installed well.

Comment: @pcGhost Thanks for the info. I've updated my post with an explanation of the phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

you must set your docmuent as utf-8 encode.

method-1: add following html code to your page

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

method-2: using php code like below

```
<?
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");  
echo “hello”;   
?>
```

the `header` must be in the first line of your code.

it will output `“hello”` ; if you want to output `hello` please change your double-quote to `'hello'`or `"hello"`. because your current double-quote are not english.

Comment: worked. would be please if you just edit it tell why it worked this way on mac and without it on ubuntu etc. ?

Comment: @pcGhost i just upgraded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can quote with quote **'**, double-quote **"**.

Your double quotes are supposed to be **"** not **“** or **”**.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem With encoded You Must Make It `UTF-8` (`utf8_encode`)

```
string utf8_encode ( string $data )
```

Note If Not Work That Mean Problem With Your Pc or Browsers Then Go To Langs In Control panal..
Hope Hear Your Answer...